# Cannot subscript a value of type '[String: AnyObject]' with an index of type 'String'

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

This is not a duplicate of the question

Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]?' with an index of type 'String'

or

Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : String]?' with an index of type 'String'

The reason is because my dictionary is not optional, which was the problem with that question.  Why is it that I can't subscript this...

[image]

Comment: maybe `alert.sourceID = Int(msg["srcID"])`

Comment: alert.sourceID = msg["srcID"] as? Int
This seems to have worked.
Which is weird, because what it complains about appears to be something else

Answer (score 0):

Accessing dictionaries with a subscript always returns an optional.  This is because you can't tell the dictionary that your are always going to use a subscript that exists in the keys list.  (even if you could, it wouldn't believe you :).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Still weird that it does not complain about the actual problem (using the return value not as an optional).

Comment: No, the actual problem was that the return type was not the same as the type that I was assigning to; the problem is not that the return type is optional, since fixing it by casting with as? still results in an optional return value, but the problem is fixed.